# Can we give specific color to some text in plist..?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, plist

I have plist file in which i have to give color to Arbic text only to make it different from others. I don't want to find text and then give color programatically.

Comment: which plist are you talking about?

Comment: property list in ios

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

As you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD) plist file are only structures for data management

> Property lists organize data into named values and lists of values using several object types.

So you can store there the information you need, as the color for arabic text, but you have to fetch it and assign to views programmatically